# How to add data with same name to database as array? (PDO)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, sql-insert

In a system with bus services, I want to save the intermediate stops and their times in the database. Since there are multiple intermediate stops and arrival times, I want to save and display them as an array in the database.
Honestly, I tried for a few days, but I couldn't find any results. I've never needed anything like this before.

Here is everything you need:

First of all my problem is that it is added to the database like this:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb9DG.png)

and this is my code,

```
<select class="form-control mt-3" name="ara_durak[]">
    <option value="12">Ankara</option>
    <option value="14">Balıkesir</option>
    <option value="13">İzmir</option>
</select>

<input type="time" class="form-control mt-3" name="ara_durak_saat[]">
<input type="time" class="form-control mt-3" name="ara_durak_saat[]">
<input type="time" class="form-control mt-3" name="ara_durak_saat[]">
```

```
  if(isset($_POST['seferEkle'])){
    $sorgu = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO seferler SET
        sefer_no=:sefer_no,
        kalkis=:kalkis,
        varis=:varis,
        ara_durak=:ara_durak,
        ara_durak_saat=:ara_durak_saat,
        kalkis_tarih=:kalkis_tarih,
        varis_tarih=:varis_tarih,
        kaptan_id=:kaptan_id,
        arac_id=:arac_id
    ");
    $sonuc = $sorgu->execute(array(
        'sefer_no' => $_POST['sefer_no'],
        'kalkis' => $_POST['kalkis'],
        'ara_durak' => $_POST['ara_durak'],
        'ara_durak_saat' => $_POST['ara_durak_saat'],
        'varis' => $_POST['varis'],
        'kalkis_tarih' => $_POST['kalkis_tarih'],
        'varis_tarih' => $_POST['varis_tarih'],
        'kaptan_id' => $_POST['kaptan_id'],
        'arac_id' => $_POST['arac_id']
    ));
  }
```

an image of my form,

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTgy9.png)

This is how I want to show the information to the user when the addition is complete:

[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut1yu.png)

I tried adding the data like this:

```
$sorgu = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO seferler SET
    sefer_no=:sefer_no,
    kalkis=:kalkis,
    varis=:varis,
    ara_durak[]=:ara_durak,
    ara_durak_saat[]=:ara_durak_saat,
    kalkis_tarih=:kalkis_tarih,
    varis_tarih=:varis_tarih,
    kaptan_id=:kaptan_id,
    arac_id=:arac_id
");
$sonuc = $sorgu->execute(array(
    'sefer_no' => $_POST['sefer_no'],
    'kalkis' => $_POST['kalkis'],
    'ara_durak' => $_POST['ara_durak'],
    'ara_durak_saat' => $_POST['ara_durak_saat'],
    'varis' => $_POST['varis'],
    'kalkis_tarih' => $_POST['kalkis_tarih'],
    'varis_tarih' => $_POST['varis_tarih'],
    'kaptan_id' => $_POST['kaptan_id'],
    'arac_id' => $_POST['arac_id']
));
```

and this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ara_durak']);$i++)

{

$araDurak = $_POST['ara_durak'][$i];
$araDurakSaat =$_POST['ara_durak_saat'][$i];

}
$sorgu = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO seferler SET
    sefer_no=:sefer_no,
    kalkis=:kalkis,
    varis=:varis,
    ara_durak=:ara_durak,
    ara_durak_saat=:ara_durak_saat,
    kalkis_tarih=:kalkis_tarih,
    varis_tarih=:varis_tarih,
    kaptan_id=:kaptan_id,
    arac_id=:arac_id
");
$sonuc = $sorgu->execute(array(
    'sefer_no' => $_POST['sefer_no'],
    'kalkis' => $_POST['kalkis'],
    'ara_durak' => $araDurak,
    'ara_durak_saat' => $araDurakSaat,
    'varis' => $_POST['varis'],
    'kalkis_tarih' => $_POST['kalkis_tarih'],
    'varis_tarih' => $_POST['varis_tarih'],
    'kaptan_id' => $_POST['kaptan_id'],
    'arac_id' => $_POST['arac_id']
));
```

but this just gives me the last value in the array [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lflU.png)

Please excuse my english. I ask for your help and i love you all <3

Comment: how many is the count of $_POST['ara_durak']

Comment: `but this just gives me the last value in the array`...well yes, because you did the prepare and execute after the loop had finished. So what else did you expect? If you want to insert each value from the array, move the prepare and execute inside the loop. Then you'll get a new row for each item in the array. If that's not what you want, then please make clearer precisely what you are trying to achieve.